# How to dynamically change the style of a single item of a mapped array in React

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I am trying to change the background of a baseLayer when it is clicked. The code beneath makes all the baseLayers blue when the button is clicked, but I only want the clicked item to be blue.

```
import React, { useState } from 'react'
import uuid from 'uuid/v1'

const BaseLayers = (props) => {
let tacos = props.tacos;
const [background, setBackground] = useState({ isSelected: false, item: '' });
return (
    <div className='base-layers'>
    <div className="base-layers-info" >START BY CHOOSING A BASE LAYER</div>
        { Array.isArray(tacos.base_layers) && tacos.base_layers.map(item => {
            return  <div className="base-layer" key={uuid()} id={item.title} **style={{ backgroundColor: background.isSelected ? 'blue' : 'red' }} >**
                        <h4 className="base-layer-title">{ item.title }</h4>
                        <img src={require('../img/taco-cards.jpg')} alt="taco" />
                        <div className="base-layer-ingredients-container">
                        { item.ingredients.map(item => {
                            if(typeof item === 'string'){
                                return   <h6 className="base-layer-ingredients" key={uuid()}>{ item }</h6>
                            }
                            if(typeof item === 'object'){
                                return  <h6 className="base-layer-ingredients" key={uuid()}>{ item.title }</h6>
                                return  <h6 className="base-layer-ingredients" key={uuid()}>{ item.ingredients }</h6>
                            }
                        }) }
                        </div>
                        <button className="base-layer-button" onClick={(e) => {
                            props.setBaseLayer(e.target.parentElement.id);
                            **setBackground({ isSelected: !background.isSelected, item: e.target.parentElement.id });**
                        }} >
                            Choose this base layer
                        </button>
                        <div className="base-layer-tags-container">
                        { item.tags.map(item => {
                            return   <h6 className="base-layer-tags" key={uuid()}>{ item }</h6>
                        }) }
                        </div>
                    </div>
        }) }
    </div>
);
}

export default BaseLayers;
```

Comment: You should have somewhere `if(background.isSelected && background.item == id) ` in order to change the css class

Comment: Glad you solved it!

Comment: If you upvote my comment would be really appreciated. thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should be as simple as changing the colour logic line to:

```
style={{ backgroundColor: (background.item === item.title && background.isSelected) ? 'blue' : 'red' }}
```

Since you're using the item's title as it's ID. This logic will work if you only want to allow 1 item to be selected at a time.

There's is a flaw in this though, if you have 2 tiles with the same title, when you select 1 of the tiles, both will turn blue! This is because their ID's (titles) are the same. To solve for this, I suggest you add an ID to an item when it is created, using UUID. It will also mean you can use that same ID as the key.